# How to cast string array to Type in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using ASPxGridView PerformCallback method to pass javascript value to behind code, it works. But I need to cast or convert string array in type and bind into ASPxGridView. How can I do it?

```
  protected void detailGrid_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        Group [] data = (Group)e.Parameters.Split(';');

        List<Group> l = new List<Group>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            l.Add(data[i]);
        }

        XFGridView1.DataSource = data;
        XFGridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you need ? do you want an object of Group class against each string element in the array ?

Comment: Ya. This is I want . Thank for clear define I need.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ works fine for "converting" or "selecting":

```
IEnumerable<Group> data = e.Parameters.Split(';').Select(p=>new Group(p));  
//or
IEnumerable<Group> data = e.Parameters.Split(';').Select(p=>new Group{SomeProperty=p});
```

assuming your Group class has a constructor that takes the string value or some property you wish to populate, respectively.

Comment: +1 for the LINQ approach, you may use `.ToArray()` at the end to get an Array of Groups as required by OP

Comment: I suspect that the GridView doesn't actually require an array, but probably (hopefully?) a more general interface like IEnumerable or IList.. in which case .ToList() would also be an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx)

Suppose your`Group` class is like:

```
class Group
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do:

```
string parameters = "abc,def,hij,klm,nop";
string[] myArray = parameters.Split(',');
Group[] groupArray  = Array.ConvertAll<string, Group>(myArray, delegate(string str)
             {
                 return  new Group { MyProperty = str };

             });
```

The above code will take a string `parameters` split it on character (`'`) and then converts the array of string to `Group` array using Array.ConvertAll, The `Group` class has a property `MyProperty` which will be filled with the string element.